# using gIntersect to find pair-wise intersection of multiple SpatialPolygons?

Tags: r, spatial

I'd like to produce a spatial object containing all the pairwise intersections for a list of spatial polygons. It's easy enough to manually use gIntersect for the intersection of just two layers, but I'd like to find all pair-wise intersections simultaneously. I have 13 polygons so there are 156 different combinations of pairs to check for overlap.  Either lapply or a for loop seems like it might be able to work, but I think I'd need a matrix of all the possible combinations of spatial polygons.

Here is a gist for a subsample of the data:

https://gist.github.com/dwwolfson/b1dc7b9c084233a4a36401f7e7061897

Here is what I've tried so far:

```
# Overlap in spring and summer of 2016
library(dplyr)
library(gdata)
library(sp)
library(rgdal)
library(rgeos)
library(raster)
library(spatstat)

#Import Data  (from gist)
df16<-df16.sub
#Extract only locations between April 1 to August 1, 2016
sub16<-df16[df16$loctime>"2016-03-31"&df16$loctime<"2016-08-01",]
#Subset by age
colts.16<-sub16[sub16$age=="colt",]
df<-colts.16
df$id<-as.factor(df$id)

#extract coordinates
coordinates(df)<-c("location.long", "location.lat")
#define coordinate ref system
proj4string(df)<-CRS("+proj=longlat +datum=WGS84")
#reproject
df<-spTransform(df, CRS("+proj=aea +lat_1=29.5 +lat_2=45.5 +lat_0=37.5
                        +lon_0=-96 +x_0=0 +y_0=0 +ellps=GRS80 +datum=NAD83 +units=m +no_defs "))
colnames(df@coords)<-c("x", "y")
sp.df<-as.data.frame(df)
crane.names<-as.list(unique(sp.df$id))
testdat<-sp.df

temp.crane<-NULL
temp.crane.day<-NULL
dat.summary<-NULL
tempdat<-NULL
firstday<-NULL
lastday<-NULL
dat.summary<-NULL
i<-NULL
j<-NULL
#loop to condense points into just roost sites
for(i in 1:length(unique(testdat$id))){
  temp.crane<-testdat[testdat$id==crane.names[[i]],]
  if(nrow(temp.crane)>0){
    current.crane<-as.character(crane.names[[i]])
    temp.days<-as.list(unique(temp.crane$day))
    days.vec<-unlist(temp.days)
    firstday<-days.vec[1]
    lastday<-last(days.vec)
    for(j in seq.int(from=firstday, to=lastday)){
      tempdat<-temp.crane[which(temp.crane$day==j),]    
      firstrow<-tempdat[1,]
      lastrow<-tempdat[nrow(tempdat),]
      daylocs<-rbind(firstrow, lastrow)

      if((j-1)<firstday)
      {daylocs$night.dist<-NA}
      else{
        prevdat<-temp.crane[which(temp.crane$day==j-1),]    
        firstrow<-prevdat[1,]
        lastrow<-prevdat[nrow(prevdat),]
        prevdaylocs<-rbind(firstrow, lastrow)

        daylocs$night.dist<-sqrt((daylocs$x[1]-prevdaylocs$x[2])^2+(daylocs$y[1]-prevdaylocs$y[2])^2)
      }
            dat.summary<-rbind(dat.summary, daylocs)
          }
  }
}

roosts<-dat.summary
temp.buffer<-NULL
temp.crane<-NULL
current.crane<-NULL
temp.id<-NULL
temp.sp.df<-NULL
buff.spdf<-NULL
crane.names<-as.list(unique(roosts$id))
test<-NULL
#create list of SpatialPolygons
for(i in 1:length(unique(roosts$id))){
  temp.crane<-roosts[roosts$id==crane.names[[i]],]
  current.crane<-as.character(crane.names[[i]])
  coordinates(temp.crane)<-c("x","y")
  proj4string(temp.crane)<-CRS("+proj=aea +lat_1=29.5 +lat_2=45.5 +lat_0=37.5
                          +lon_0=-96 +x_0=0 +y_0=0 +ellps=GRS80 +datum=NAD83 +units=m +no_defs ")
  temp.buffer<-gBuffer(temp.crane, width=3000)
  test[i]<-list(temp.buffer)
}
```

I tried to adapt a question about something that kinda related using the combn() function where test is a list of spatial polygons:

```
combos1<-combn(test,2)
for(k in length(combos1)){
i<-combos[1,k]
j<-combos[2,k]
print(paste("intersecting", i, j))
int[k]<-gIntersection(i,j, byid=T)
}
```

I get the following error message:

```
Error in identical(spgeom1@proj4string, spgeom2@proj4string) :                         
trying to get slot "proj4string" from an object of a basic class ("list") with no slots
```

The following doesn't produce an error, but on visual inspection in ArcMap, it's not getting all the occasions of overlap, probably just the last round.

```
   overlap<-list()
for(i in length(test)){
for(j in length(test)){
overlap<-gIntersection(test[[i]],test[[j]])
} 
}
```

I think my problem is that I need to "rbind" or merge all the spatial polygon objects from each iteration into one list. Maybe if I first create SpatialPolygonDataframes instead of SpatialPolygons it'd be easier to combine?  I also need to avoid i and j being the same number or else I'll get the same polygon overlapping itself.

I tried to store each iteration's overlap into a list of spatial objects using the following code, but the spRbind chokes on the first run because object intended to store the results starts out as NULL, I think.

```
library(maptools)
over.list<-NULL

for(i in length(test)){
for(j in length(test)){
overlap<-gIntersection(test[[i]],test[[j]])
over.list<-spRbind(over.list, overlap)
} 
}
```

Comment: What is `test` ? Can you provide a reproducible example ? Below, I added a SpatialPolygon object in your question. Can you try your script using this example so that we can see where is the problem. I don't expect `combn` to return a SpatialPolygon object, so that `gIntersection(i,j)` is not supposed to work.

Comment: Here you can find an example SpatialPolygon that can be incorporated in your question as `test` : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43524140/extract-number-of-raster-cells-included-in-a-spatialpolygons/43542729#43542729

Comment: Here is a gist and all the code to get to the point where I was at.  None of that is too essential, mainly just that I'm now at the point where I have SpatialPolygons and want to find the all the pair-wise intersections of the group.

Comment: Indeed, this was useful because now I know how you built `test` !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way you build `test` is very particular. This is not a Spatial object, which makes it particular to use...
The way you use `combn` is not correct. It can not use a list of objects like this. The documentation says:

> ?combn
>   x vector source for combinations, or integer n for x <- seq_len(n).

So you should use it as is.
The example and data you give is not easy to be used as is. I had to modify differents things. Next time, you should provide a simple example that corresponds to your data problem. Refer to: [How to make a great R reproducible example?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example)
As far as I can understand from what your looking at, I propose you a possible way. But you need to learn what is the organization of `SpatialPolygons` objects in R to make your script cleaner.

So here, I use `combn` in a usable way. I retrieve all polygons intersections in a list as you did. When the intersection is not NULL, I also retrieve it as a `Polygons` object to be able to gather all Polygons as a `SpatialPolygons`:

```
combos <- combn(length(test),2)
int <- vector("list", length = ncol(combos))
Polygons.list <- list()
k.poly <- 0 # Number of non-null polygons
for(k in 1:ncol(combos)){
  i<-combos[1,k]
  j<-combos[2,k]
  print(paste("intersecting", i, j))
  int.tmp <- gIntersection(test[[i]],test[[j]], byid=FALSE)
  if (!is.null(int.tmp)) {
    k.poly <- k.poly + 1
    int[[k]] <- int.tmp
    Polygons.list[[k.poly]] <- int[[k]]@polygons[[1]]
    Polygons.list[[k.poly]]@ID <- paste(k.poly)
  }
}

all.Intersections <- SpatialPolygons(Polygons.list)
plot(all.Intersections, col = "red")
```

Comment: Thanks very much for your help and the input on using Stack Overflow.